# Is calling `disposed(by:)` necessary in any case?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

As the title, is it necessary to call `disposed(by:)` in any case? If yes, why?

Consider a simple example like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  let button = UIButton()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    button.rx.tap.bind(onNext: { _ in
      print("Button tapped!")
    })
    // Does this make any retain cycle here?
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, for example, when you want the listener to be destroyed when the creating controller is destroyed

Comment: Yes, just because when you view controller will be deallocated then `disposebag` will be deallocated and memory will be cleaned, and nor retain cycle will be formed.

Comment: But you don't need a DisposeBag in that simple example above. The subscription is disposed when the view controller is deallocated.

Comment: Using a DisposeBag is good practice but is not always necessary. There are also other ways to dispose a subscription like takeUntil for example. You can read more [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#disposing).

Comment: @FabioFelici yes. And the button `tap` sequence is using `takeUntil` internally. That's why is fine my example above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not necessary to call `.disposed(by:)` in every case.

If you have an Observable that you know will eventually send a stop event, and you know that you want to keep listening to that observable until it does so, then there is no reason/need to dispose the subscription and therefore no need to insert the disposable into a dispose bag.

---

The reason `.subscribe` and its ilk return a Disposable is so that the calling code can end the subscription *before* the observable has completed. The calling code ends the subscription by calling `dispose()` on the disposable returned. Otherwise, the subscription will continue until the source observable sends a stop event (either completed or error.)

If the calling code doesn't dispose the subscription, and the source observable doesn't send a stop event, then the subscription will continue to operate *even if all other code involved has lost all references to the objects involved in the subscription.*

So for example, if you put this in a viewDidLoad:

```
_ = Observable<Int>.interval(.seconds(1), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
```

The code above will continue to print values long after the view controller that created it ceases to exist.

In the example you presented, the UIButton object *will* emit a completed event when it is deinitialized, so if you want to listen to the button right up until that happens, putting the disposable in a dispose bag isn't necessary.

Ignoring disposables means you need to be very cognizant as to which Observables complete and which ones don't, but if you have that understanding, you *can* ignore them. Just remember that the next developer down the line, or future you, won't have as good an understanding of the code as you do.

Comment: I 100% agree with you. And I've just realized that the `tap` sequence is using `takeUntil` internally, that's why the resources will be deallocated when the button is gone away. I think there are so many people who know that they should use `disposed(by)` but don't really understand the reason behind it. Thanks so much for such a super-detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Is there any documentation on this behavior?

Comment: Look in the "GettingStarted.md" documentation of the RxSwift library.